# Timeshift backup, change directory as one by default is quite strange. Using terminal

Tags: terminal, backup

Everyone is mentioning using GUI to configure timeshift but is it possible to change settings and specifically backup directory from terminal?

After the installation for some reason timeshift is using quite strange path for the backups `/var/www/webuser/web/log`.

Why did it use that directory? I have no idea but it's getting me in constant loop of infinite backup.

Basically I want to just backup system on the same hdd in a folder which will be excluded, for example in `/timeshift`

I tried looking in `/etc/timeshift/timeshift.json` file but I just see empty unconfigured config file

```
{
  "backup_device_uuid" : "",
  "parent_device_uuid" : "",
  "do_first_run" : "true",
  "btrfs_mode" : "false",
  "include_btrfs_home" : "false",
  "stop_cron_emails" : "true",
  "schedule_monthly" : "false",
  "schedule_weekly" : "false",
  "schedule_daily" : "false",
  "schedule_hourly" : "false",
  "schedule_boot" : "false",
  "count_monthly" : "2",
  "count_weekly" : "3",
  "count_daily" : "5",
  "count_hourly" : "6",
  "count_boot" : "5",
  "snapshot_size" : "0",
  "snapshot_count" : "0",
  "exclude" : [
  ],
  "exclude-apps" : [
  ]
}
```

I don't think timeshift even use this config file, or at least from my setup it's not using it.
I tried this on Debian 10 on a VPS machine.
So can I use it from terminal and is there an initial configuration?

Answer (score 1):

It does use this config file. I just tested it. You have to enter the UUID of the device where you want to store the snapshots as "backup_device_uuid". I'm still struggling how to set up the backups on a regular basis. Isst possible as a service or would I do this as a cronjob?

Comment: I did setup the "backup_device_uuid" but my guess is since backup is on the same hdd somehow timeshift get confused with the path. I guess you can run it as cronjob, there is additional command `--tags` and `--tags D` would be for daily backups but that don't work either. Eventually I moved on and use `rsync` Arch wiki have a great documentation on backups with rsync https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/rsync#Installation

Comment: You can also enter something for exclusions. So, I'd give it a try and exclude the folder where you store the backup.

I had to use the system restore. Worked pretty well, so I assume, I will have a combination of rsync/rsnapshot and timeshift.